# 'Dcoder' exercise failed test case

Tags: java

[Screenshot of exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkTIG.png)

So I'm a beginner at programming and I thought this short exercise (see attached image) was quite easy, but when I submit the code it gives back results for the test cases. I failed one of the test cases and I can't figure out what would be wrong (Sadly you can't see the input from that test case).

This is the code I had:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int a = sc.nextInt(); // first distance
    int m = sc.nextInt(); // fare for distance a
    int n = sc.nextInt(); // fare for remaining distance
    int d = sc.nextInt(); // total distance

    int fare = (a*m)+((d-a)*n);

    System.out.println(fare);
```

Can anyone see in what situation this calculation would be incorrect? It looks so easy but somehow I can't think of the solution right now.

In case this is relevant the sample input is: 1 2 3 5
Giving the output: 14

Comment: From the wording of the question, I think the first `a` km is a set price.

Comment: `a` is not part of the distance traveled. It's just a threshold where the calculation switches from one price to the other. Let's put it this way: if `d` is less than `a`, will the driver start paying the customer? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is not part of the distance traveled. It's just a threshold where the calculation switches from one price to the other. Let's put it this way: if `d` is less than `a`, will the driver start paying the customer? No. ;)

You should calculate the price for the first part of the route and then conditionally, if `d` is greater than `a`, add to that the price for the remaining part of the route.